# When should you "rebuild project" in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compilation-types.html?search=rebuild

According to that description of complication types, rebuilding a project recompiles all source files, and recommends its use when "classpath entries have changed, for example, SDKs or libraries being used added, removed or altered."

I would appreciate some help interpreting this. I can imagine it may be necessary to recompile your class if a dependency changes or is removed, as it may no longer compile successfully. However, why would any *new* classes cause you to recompile existing ones?

Comment: Where do you see that recompilation is needed for new Java files? You'll obviously need to repackage a JAR file , but that's after compilation

Comment: For a regular project you won't need that. However there are complex projects. I, for example, am contributing to a big project with several plugins and classes which are dynamically build (using ant and other scripts). Sometimes classes are not built correctly or dependencies aren't correctly fetched or the built order breaks something. In that case hitting **rebuild** and similar tools often fixes the issues.

Comment: Super weired. Suddenly (probably after an update) Rebuild-Functionality is gone. Build functionality still exists (on the context menu of a project). Ok it exists as a major menu entry on 'Build' menu. Why and how was it removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rebuild Project" basically is a clean build, compiling everything, rather than the typical incremental build which just builds classes that have changed since the last build.

> However, why would any new classes cause you to recompile existing ones?

A primary reason would be to ensure there is no duplication. For example, I've seen cases where someone adds a different version of a library that is already on the classpath. For example, they want to use `FancyUtils` from the `foo-utilis` library (that was added in v2). When he tries to use it and doesn't find it, he just assumes he needs to add `foo-utils-2.0` not noticing that `foo-utils-1.0` is already on the classpath. Now both versions of the library are present and that can cause issues. Maybe a class your project is using from v1 was removed and now your project doesn't compile. But if you don't do a clean build, you won't notice it because the using class has not changed and would not be recompiled.

Another possibility is the introduction of a clashing resource. While its very rare to get a clashing class as long as everyone follows good package naming conventions, I've seen it happen. But more likely, you may have two libraries that both have a commonly named resource/config file, like a `.properties` file. Again, not common... but it does happen.

In addition to those things, various strange things sometimes happen. And it's a thousand times easier to track down a quirky issue if you find it right away after adding a library (since you know that new library is a leading contender for the reason why) rather then discovering it days later and not even knowing where to start.

Personally I like to do a clean build every few hours as a sanity check. I *always* run one before a commit and after a pull & update. While it may only happen once in a blue moon, strange issues that can only be caught by a clean build do arise.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild Project is not recommended when changes are made to *existing* classes. The correct compilation type in that case is: `Compile <compilation_scope>` or `Build Project` or `Build Module` (since these are all forms of the same thing namely: compile for *some scope*).

Rebuild Project is recommended if there has been a structural change to your project, something which is likely to effect **more** than the set of classes which have changed since the last compilation.

Of course if the cost (time, CPU, memory ...) for a Rebuild Project is negligible for you then you might prefer to use that option than wonder about which of the other options might suffice on the grounds that it is a superset of the others. But, if cost is non negligible and your focus is on compiling classes which have changed since the last compilation then the correct choice is the 'smallest' of the other three options which covers the scope of your changes.

In practice you may do both; frequent builds at class, package, project or module scope with less frequent full rebuilds.